# What's the difference between Android SDK Update Sites `https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository2-1.xml` and `2-2.xml`?

Tags: android

In my Android Studio, it given two default SDK Update sites:

```
https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository2-1.xml
https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository2-2.xml
```

I use code compare tool to contrast them, then I found only several differences:

1.
[image]

2.
checksum property added type="sha1"

[image]

3.

[image]